# How do we update a custom file upload field with the Advanced Custom Field plugin?

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

```
...
$filename = mt_rand( 100,999 ) . '.pdf';
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $post_data );

if ( $post_id ) {
    $pdf_field = get_field_object( $fields['pdf'], $post_id, false, true );

    $fields = array(
        'pdf' => $pdf_field['key'],
    );

    $pdf_field = array(
        'title' => $filename,
        'filename' => $filename,
        'url' => $uploaded_uri,
        'mime_type' => 'application/pdf',
        'type' => 'application',
        'subtype' => 'pdf',
        'icon' => $icon_url,
    );

    update_field( $fields['pdf'], $pdf_field, $post_id );
}
...
```

The function `update_field` returns a custom field's post ID. This means that it is successfully inserting the custom field post. But, when we check the respective post, the file is not attached to it.

Any clue what is missing?

Comment: File upload fields might _return_ all those values, but the stored value of the field is the ID of the attachment for the file. So you need to upload the file to the media library, and then you can set the field value as its ID.

Comment: Okay, the file is already in the `Media Library`. So, all we have to do now is it set that ID to the `value` key of the array?

Comment: There is no array. Literally just `update_field( 'field_name', $attachment_id, $post_id );`

Comment: I must be a special kind of fool; wasted 6 hours on this like a splendid idiot. :-/
Thank you.

Comment: Hey, I only know because I've had to go through that before. Only way to learn ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File upload fields might *return* all those values (depending on the field settings), but those are just based on the media library attachment. The field only actually stores the ID of the attachment for the file as its value. So to populate a File field programatically, you just need to set an attachment ID as the field value.

So once you have the attachment ID, you just need to do this:

```
update_field( 'field_name', $attachment_id, $post_id );
```